# When try to boot only get `grub>`

Tags: dual-boot

I have an HP TouchSmart with 2 TB HD and Windows 7. Made a partion of 1 TB to locate Ubuntu and have dual boot. When I get the choice for Windows 7 or Ubuntu and run Ubuntu I only get

```
grub>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an **Ubuntu Live CD** or **USB** and boot from it.
2. Check if Ubuntu files are still there. If your Ubuntu partition is ok, maybe there's some problem with the Kernel. You may try to install a **new** one...